# Making mathematical expressions as balanced trees as possible

Tags: optimization, trees, arithmetic

I am having some trouble with turning the following mathematical expressions into as balanced binary trees as possible.

This is what I have done so far, but is there a way to make them even more balanced?

$( − 3)(^2 +  − 1)$

[image]

$4( − 1)( − 2)( − 3)$

[image]

Comment: Are you allowed to apply laws of arithmetics?

Comment: I assume since the only instructions given are ''Give the following mathematical expressions as trees, where each node contains a
single numeral value or one of the basic operations +, -, * or / . Make the trees as
balanced as possible.''

Comment: Then it's simple: just draw all the trees. There are not too many. Use the example to come up with an algorithm and arguments of correctness.

Comment: Can you use directly $y^2$ as a leaf?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since these are *mathematical* expressions, you can bracket the second one as (4 (x-1)) ((y-2) (z-3)) to make it more balanced. In many programming languages this wouldn't be allowed, because with floating point arithmetic, the order of operations will often change the result.

Can't see any way to improve the first one.

Comment: for the first: $((y*y)+y)-1 = (y*y)+(y-1)$